# Cron Expression with ExecutionTime not giving proper output

Tags: java, cron

I am trying to make custom scheduler in my application using a corn expression but it's seems like corn expression is not calculating proper time for next execution, help me to solve this issue to get correct time.

Below is my code:

```
ZonedDateTime now = ZonedDateTime.parse("2022-01-17T15:57+05:30[Asia/Calcutta]");
        
        ExecutionTime executionTime = ExecutionTime.forCron(parser.parse("0 0/7 * * * ?"));

        Duration nextRunDate = executionTime.timeToNextExecution(now).get();

        ZonedDateTime instant = now.plus(nextRunDate);
        // Create Date instance out of Instant
        Date dateToRun = Date.from(instant.toInstant());
        System.out.println(nextRunDate.toString());
        System.out.println(dateToRun);
```

and output which is I am getting for this is as below:

```
PT3M
Mon Jan 17 16:00:00 IST 2022
```

Now this is wrong as it is giving duration of 3 minutes but in expression I am want it to run at every 7 minutes so output should be as below:

```
PT7M
Mon Jan 17 16:04:00 IST 2022
```

but if I set time as below:

```
ZonedDateTime now = ZonedDateTime.parse("2022-01-17T15:14+05:30[Asia/Calcutta]");
```

it is giving proper output:

```
PT7M
Mon Jan 17 15:21:00 IST 2022
```

Please someone help how can we resolve this issue? what is wrong am I doing here?

Comment: Can you try with cron expression as */7  * * * *

Comment: this expression is for seconds I am trying for minutes.

Comment: From what i have observed is the expression is valid from the start of the hour only..that means it will run at multiples 7 minutes starting from 0 only so if we specify like 2022-01-17T15:37+05:30 it will run at next multiple of 7 ie at 2022-01-17T15:42 , for 2022-01-17T15:39 also..it will run at 2022-01-17T15:42.

Comment: Yes but it should generate new time with difference of 7 minutes not multiples of 7.